# Finding peaks in audio spectrogram

Tags: python, signal-processing, audio-fingerprinting

**Introduction :** I am working on [audio fingerprinting](http://willdrevo.com/fingerprinting-and-audio-recognition-with-python/) and having some doubts regarding peak detection in the spectrogram, my input is a wav file with spectrogram as  : [image]
The method I'm implementing is given [here](https://github.com/worldveil/dejavu)

**Problem :** The peaks returning from the get_2Dpeaks() method are not overlapping with the above spectrogram. On different files the plot changes drastically. for the above file used, output of get_2D_peaks() is :
[image]

It seems like I'm not fitting the signal data well, does anyone have any ideas or thoughts on how can I find the peaks in the spectrogram and also plot them ?

Answer (score 0):

Audio fingerprinting using spectrogram peaks is discussed in [Fundamentals of Music Processing: Audio Identification](https://www.audiolabs-erlangen.de/resources/MIR/FMP/C7/C7S1_AudioIdentification.html#Audio-Fingerprints-Based-on-Spectral-Peaks).

It provides code for finding the peaks of a magnitude spectrogram, based on `scipy.ndimage`. This code is provided below:

```py
def compute_constellation_map(Y, dist_freq=7, dist_time=7, thresh=0.01):
    """Compute constellation map (implementation using image processing)

    Notebook: C7/C7S1_AudioIdentification.ipynb

    Args:
        Y (np.ndarray): Spectrogram (magnitude)
        dist_freq (int): Neighborhood parameter for frequency direction (kappa) (Default value = 7)
        dist_time (int): Neighborhood parameter for time direction (tau) (Default value = 7)
        thresh (float): Threshold parameter for minimal peak magnitude (Default value = 0.01)

    Returns:
        Cmap (np.ndarray): Boolean mask for peak structure (same size as Y)
    """
    result = ndimage.maximum_filter(Y, size=[2*dist_freq+1, 2*dist_time+1], mode='constant')
    Cmap = np.logical_and(Y == result, result > thresh)
    return Cmap
```